# How to find what kind of network am i connected to? Is it a LAN or a WAN or a MAN ? in windows

Tags: networking

How to tell whether the network i am currently connected to is a Local Area Network or a Wide Area network or a Metropolitan Area network ? Also what is a MAN(is it a link between two or more buildings or anything else)?

Comment: How (by what attribute) do you differentiate between LAN/WAN/MAN when considering this manually? Then we can try to find an automatic way of getting that info. Also what OS do you use?

Comment: I use a windows 7 os

Comment: I guess you are always connected to a LAN, which then itself may be connected to some kind or larger corporate network or directly to internet. I still don't understand what kind of information about that network do you need...

Comment: did you tried checking if your IP address is Public or Private? for MAN check this reference http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolitan_area_network

Comment: Are you actually trying to accomplish something, or are you just curious?  If there is a larger goal in mind, please edit your question and actually ask it, and we can help you out.  If you're just curious, then nevermind

Comment: Thanks all i kinda understood most of the  things . suppose I am in an organization (company) .My only confusion is that how can we see whether there is a MAN connection between two branches of the same organization in two different places.